# Search Page with Ajax (algorithm)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I want to make a search page like google that when i input 'ex' then with the ajax we recognition that the user intend to input 'example' or 'exam' or ... 
what is the algorithm for making a page like this ? 
is the query of mysql like : `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE upper($field) LIKE'%$find%'"` ? 
Thanks in Advance .

Comment: Yes and no. Honestly no one knows the true algorithm, but when you are doing something like this, it's best to cache (for autocomplete). If you are just doing a 1 time search and trying to find anything similar to 'ex', then this query would be perfectly fine. Also, if you want it to start with ex, then do `$find%` instead of `%$find%`, since `%` is a wildcard.

Comment: just refer this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909210/jquery-autosuggest-example

Comment: @matt :Honestly no one knows the true algorithm ; its mean that no one knows the algorithm of google search page ? or the query ?

Comment: @SriveKobz no one knows how google does their queries. That is what makes google google. They keep it a secret. But, people have an idea of how to do it and it really just comes down to caching and indexing. (easier said than done). Now if this isn't going to happen all the time, then indexing should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

the query is almost this
`mysql_query("select * from users where queryfield like '$q%' order by queryfield");`
you may use jquery autocomplete to ease your work

```
<input type="text" id="populate">
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(function() {

    $("#populate").autocomplete({
        url: 'search.php',
        cache: false,
        onItemSelect: function(item) {
            window.location.href=item.data;
            document.getElementById('populate').value='';

        },
    });

});


    </script>
```

for complete source:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote

Answer (score 0):

I think it works like this, suppose we have two tables, one are the articles / links in demand, others are the key words 'search engine breaks', but what good these keywords? to me, is a popularity index, because it is the most sought after, this index is based on that ..

The more a person searches, eg '**i an legend**' or '**legend an i**', '**movie legend**', '**god is legend**' .. the word 'legend' was searched four times, and its index will be built based on this, but .. you have a limit order, they may have many words that have been sought, but did not even enter the search or in addition

You will have to do something like this, create a table, where it will update every 25% of searches, the words .. when the user is typing, you show the suggestions.

You should do something, it would bring better results for those who use the search, however, you can resolve the suggest problem with `jQuery Autocomplete`